Cannot find SDL2/SDL_image.h file installed through Homebrew
Trying to set up SDL properly on my machine, but my program can't find the header files when compiling.
Trying to get an example SDL program:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 
    // returns zero on success else non-zero
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("GAME",
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                       1000, 1000, 0);
    while (1)
        ;
 
    return 0;
}

...to compile:
clang -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/lib -lSDL2 -o main main.cpp

...and received this error:
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL_image.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

So far, I have updated my Include paths, with
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/lib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/include
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/include/SDL2

and I have also updated my .zprofile with
export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib

Any help?

Does the file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h exist? Note that you should use clang++ not clang for building c++ code

I usually use clang++ -I$(brew --prefix sdl2)/include -L$(brew --prefix sdl2)/lib -o main main.cpp -LSDL2

"as well as a" - as a what?

I would argue that it's time for cmake or some build system.

That header (SDL2/image.h) is part of the sdl2_image package. You need to install that as well.
You will also need to link with SDL2_image. You can add -lsdl2_image to your existing commandline, but I recommend asking pkg-config for the specific flags:
clang++ -O2 main.cpp -o main $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2 sdl2_image)

These instructions are generic so they work for almost everyone, and if not still they know which packages to hunt down.
